# Created QuerySet gives different outcomes and depends on useless code between creation and it's actual use

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm having an API project with Titles of movies/books etc and Genres. Title and Genre models are having many-to-many connection. GenreSerializer is nested in Title's field. Also for connection I use intermediate table GenreTitle (like, genre_id - title_id).

What's happenning: I have TitleWriteSerializer with Update method which can be used to patch added Title fields including change of 'genre' in GenreTitle table (also new genre can be created). Probably I'm doing things not in best way but what logic I follow in patch method with 'genre' field: I save a queryset (genre_items_to_delete) in GenreTitle table refered to title_id, then create a new lines in GenreTitle based on request's data ('genre' field), and only after that (creation with validation) delete items in saved queryset(genre_items_to_delete).

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    """Update title"""

    # Delete exist rows in GenreTitle table and create new
    # based on request data. Delete items after creation.
    if 'genre' in validated_data.keys():

        # Remember all rows in GenreTitle table to be deleted later.
        genre_items_to_delete = GenreTitle.objects.filter(title=instance.id)

        # Not clear why without this line it doesn't work.
        print('====Genre items to delete: ', len(genre_items_to_delete))

        # Create new lines in GenreTitle
        genres = validated_data.get('genre')
        for genre in genres:
            current_genre, status = Genre.objects.get_or_create(**genre)
            GenreTitle.objects.create(
                genre=current_genre,
                title=instance
            )

        # If succeed with creation (no validation errors) delete
        # items in saved queryset.
        if len(genre_items_to_delete) > 0:
            for item in genre_items_to_delete:
                item.delete()

    instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
    instance.year = validated_data.get('year', instance.year)
    instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
    instance.category = validated_data.get('category', instance.category)
    instance.save()

    return instance
```

Link to Serializer file:
https://github.com/wenerikk5/api_yamdb/blob/3e775dd16ff36f7b29b84e87d03cca1aed66c464/api_yamdb/api/serializers.py#L155

Link to Views file:
https://github.com/wenerikk5/api_yamdb/blob/3e775dd16ff36f7b29b84e87d03cca1aed66c464/api_yamdb/api/views.py#L163

For some reason, if I do it like that (imagine there is no line 155), updated title have an empty genre field.

[Outcome without line 155](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2sDc.png)

But if after creation of queryset (genre_items_to_delete in line 153) I will check it's length or do usless for loop via it's items - result is different, all works, genre field is not empty.

[Different result with line 155](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTcpw.png)

Tried to copy queryset to other variable, didnt work.
I see no sens in having line 155, but it somehow changes the outcome

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can leave a link to github with project but not sure that it overcomplicates my question.

Comment: I think you are having troubles at understanding 158 line, i am not very clear why you are using `validate_data` inside a conditional to `'gendre'`  i think you probably could replace this statement and just iterating on **gendres** and perform any operation and please [do not post image of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Check of genre in validation_data is required to understand wheather I need to update nested GenreTitle model or not. In Views I have 2 perform_update methods for this, one standard with serializer in argument and other one - with (serializer, data) where data is genre's dict from request. I had to make this  trick with bypassing of genre's data as validation in Views for Title also validates Genre's data like for creation (if I understood logic correstly).

Comment: Genre has unique slug constraint, so it cannot pass validation if genre is already exists . Of course I need to use exist genre's for Titles with possibility to add new one if necessary.

Comment: `get` method should return desired value of -1, then i think if you want to  replace conditional it could by `if validated_data.get("genre") != -1:`  or just created variable `genres` before and use as `genres!=-1`.

Comment: Also make sure to pass correct arguments in `get_or_create`, that should be something like `Genre.objects.get_or_create(genre=genre['genre'], title=genre['title'])`, i recommend to read [QuerySet#get-or-create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) section.

Comment: Have tried those changes (condidtion `validated_data.get('genre') !=-1` and more detailed `get_or_create` method) but outcome is the same. For some reason created QuerySet (`genre_items_to_delete`) without line 155 has different content right after creation and in delete loop. Maybe change of model table triggers program to update this queryset or it just bug?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.db.models import Q

#... 
genres = validated_data.get('genre')
for genre in genres:
    obj, created = Genre.objects.filter(
        Q(title=instance.id) 
    ).get_or_create(**genre) # optional use Q object or just get_or_create

Genre.objects.filter(genres__contains=instance.id).delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code statement are filtering **NULL** values because instance is supposed to be related to genre model and his fields, then when you use `filter` on titles and compare with the id of the object that it might be a primary key type or another id related definition. Example: `"some_title" == models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)` where the id cause a wrong match. Correct comparission should be **`instance.title`**:

```
# should match .title or .name
genre_items_to_delete = GenreTitle.objects.filter(title=instance.title)
```

Additionally you can replace some statements from update and create methods (this is optional)

create:

```
title = Title.objects.create(**validated_data)

for genre in genres:
    print("=====genre====")
    current_genre, status = Genre.objects.get_or_create(**genre)
    GenreTitle.objects.create(
        genre=current_genre,
        title=current_genre.slug #should work "title[current_genre.id].title"  
    )
```

title is supposed to contain all serialized data without genres, and you create title objects by `title=title[current_genre.id].title`:

```
>>> Title.objects.create(**validated_data) # without genres
(**validated_data) # as keyword arguments serialized
# [
#     {'id': 0, 'title': 'example title'},
#     {'id': 1, 'title': 'example title'},
#     {'id': 2, 'title': 'example title'}
# ]
```

update:

```
genres = validated_data.get('genre')
for genre in genres:
    current_genre, status = Genre.objects.get_or_create(**genre)
    GenreTitle.objects.create(
        genre=current_genre.name,
        title=current_genre.slug
    )
```

hope this help.

Answer (score -2):

Django Querysets are lazy, so in order to save id's of items I had to force queryset evaluation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) and it happened when I printed len of queryset:

```
# Not clear why without this line it doesn't work.
        print('====Genre items to delete: ', len(genre_items_to_delete))
```

Comment: please spell out how you forced it / how you'd suggest a reader to force it.